# Problem posting a comment

Tags: bug

Here we go again. I received the displayed error while trying to post a comment. Posting a comment to a different answer to the same question worked fine (it was just a test, so I deleted it again), proving that there are no issues at my end.

After this happened the first time I flushed everything and left it for a few hours, only to get the same error again.

[image]

Comment: Are these relatively recent occurrences (starting around October 28/29/30th)? It could be related to the fact that StackExchange is running out of Oregon at the moment...

Comment: Very recently. This one happened today and the other one about the close voting happened the night before.

Comment: There's no server error on our end, the next time this happens can you log the exact time (UTC) that it happens so I can look at our traffic logs?  Maybe the response pattern will help us see what's happening here.

Comment: @Nick, while I can't give you an exact time in this case I can say that it happened just a few minutes before posting this question. I really don't understand why I can post a comment to one answer but get an error when posting to a different answer to the very same question, all in the space of a minute or two.